# which boto3 API can be used to register and deregister targets

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, boto3

Is there any boto3 API available which I can directly use to deregister and register targets in a target group.
My lambda function :

1. Identifies the health of the target grp
2. If unhealthy then finds the correct IP address/instance ID to be used (it has the information beforehand)
3. **De-Register the existing Target and register new target**
4. waits for sometime and ensures the Target grp responses healthy.

For #3 I am not able to figure out if any Boto3 python api available, if you guys have any clue let me know.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [register_targets()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.register_targets) and [deregister_targets()](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#ElasticLoadBalancingv2.Client.deregister_targets) methods of the [ElasticLoadBalancingv2 Boto3 client](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/elbv2.html#client).

Comment: Thanks, it worked and this was something I was looking for. Thanks !!